# Activeresource-response gem

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, library-design

I created my first gem for Rails today. https://github.com/Fivell/activeresource-response.
This gem adds possibility to access http response object from result of activeresource call.

- I don't know how to create test for this gem.
- Also I want to ask if there is more simply and elegant way to do this?
- Is it really thread-safe?
- Other ways to write this functionllity except `alias_method`?

Here is source of library.

```
require "activeresource-response/version"
module ActiveresourceResponse
   module Connection
     def self.included(base)
       base.class_eval  <<-EOS
           alias_method :origin_handle_response, :handle_response 
           attr_reader :http_response
           def handle_response(response)
             @http_response= response
             origin_handle_response(response)
           end
        EOS
     end 
   end   
   module AddResponseMethod
     def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end
      module ClassMethods
         def add_response_method(method_name = 'http_response')
             class_eval  <<-EOS
               class << self
                 alias_method :origin_find, :find
                 def find(*arguments)
                     result = origin_find(*arguments)
                     result.class_eval("attr_reader :#{method_name}")
                     result.instance_variable_set(:"@#{method_name}", connection.http_response)
                     result
                 end
                end 
             EOS
         end   
      end
   end   
end
ActiveResource::Connection.send :include, ActiveresourceResponse::Connection
ActiveResource::Base.send :include, ActiveresourceResponse::AddResponseMethod
```

UPDATE

I made some refactoring, please look at github sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, it unnecessary to use the `included` hook methods. Since your purpose is to redefine some methods in `ActiveresourceResponse::Connection` and `Activeresource::Base`, why not just do so directly?

```
# if ActiveResource has not been loaded yet, Rails' const_missing hook
#   will load it automatically
ActiveResource::Connection.class_eval do
  alias_method :__handle_response__ :handle_response
  # ... and so on
end
ActiveResource::Base.instance_eval do
  alias_method :__find__ :find
  # ... and so on
end
```

By using `instance_eval` in the second case, we can redefine class methods with 1 less line of code, because `class << self` is unnecessary.

In `add_response_method`, it is unnecessary to pass `'http_response'` as an argument. That code will never be run with any other value, so why use an argument? Just use a literal value, it's clearer and easier to read.

*Every* time a model object is returned from `ActiveResource::Base.find`, you define the `http_response` method on it with `class_eval`. This is very inefficient -- I think you should just define a `http_response` instance method on `ActiveResource::Base`, and all model classes derived from `ActiveResource::Base` will inherit it. (Think of the work which is done to define a method -- the Ruby parser has to run on the code, it has to be compiled to bytecode, then an entry has to be made in a method table...)

I just benchmarked `Object#instance_variable_set`, and it's very fast, faster than using `instance_eval` or `instance_exec`. So I think that should stay, but don't generate a new symbol using `:"#{}"` each time. Just use something like `:@__http_response__`. (Why the "special" name? Because when you are adding instance variables to a user-defined class, you want to reduce the chances of a collision with a user-defined variable.) Of course, this will mean you can't use `attr_reader`, but that's no problem. You can just do something like: `def http_response; @__http_response__; end`

For tests, why don't you look at how `ActiveResource` itself is tested? I'm sure all that code is open-source and should be available from a public repo.

EDIT: I just looked at the GitHub repo and noticed that you changed to a thread-local variable to try to make the code thread-safe. My question is: is a single `ActiveResource::Connection` object shared by the whole application? Or each time you make a request, does it create a new `Connection` object? If it creates a new `Connection` object for each request, then using thread-local variables is unnecessary, and an instance variable would be better. If the whole application is sharing only one `Connection` object, then using the thread-local variable is a good idea.

EDIT 2: I just found a bug. If a user tries to use `add_response_method` to add an alias for `http_response`, subsequent calls to `find` will go into an infinite loop. Try it and you will see.

Comment: Thanks for you comment!!! I made debug and connection returned  the same object_id so I think yes this object is shared. 
"In add_response_method, it is unnecessary to pass 'http_response' as an argument" => user can define method name if he want to use different one. Also I can't defind http_response instance method on ActiveResource::Base because result of find and get methods can be array or even hash.

Comment: @Fivell, what difference does it make if `find` and `get` return arrays, hashes, or some other type of object? Whatever the case, each ActiveRecord model needs a `http_response` method, and the body is the same in each case: `def http_response; @http_response; end`. (That's what `attr_reader` generates for you.) Why do you want to generate this method dynamically *every time* `find` is executed?

Comment: I think it is better if you just call the method `http_response`. If the user wants to use a different name, that is what `alias` and open classes are for.

Comment: Also, even if you want to make the name of the `http_response` method configurable, you don't need to create a symbol dynamically (using `:"#{}"`) on each execution. You can just do something like this: `define_method(method_name) do @__http_response__ end`. Then assign the value with `instance_variable_set(@__http_response__, connection.http_response)`.

Comment: About the idea of allowing the user to pass a string to define the name of the `http_response` method, note that when the user `require`s your file, `http_response` will automatically be defined. So the best they can do by calling `add_response_method` is to add *another* identical method with a different name. But that's what `alias` is for.

Comment: thanks I like idea about define_method! about generating method everytime I don't understand... I just add instance variable to result (result can be array hash or Activeresource object) and reader (with user defined name - argument of add_response_method method )for it, no matter what it is. Can you explain what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @Fivell, I understand now why you want to add a reader to the object returned by `find`. I don't understand how this code could actually work, though, because `class_eval` only works when called on modules and classes. Anyways, when you `class_eval "attr_reader :method_name"`, you are defining a method, the same as when you do `def method_name; end`. This is rather inefficient. Even more inefficient is the fact that you are `eval`ing a string. *Every time* you do this, the Ruby parser has to run on that string, and it has to be compiled to bytecode.

Comment: I benchmarked, and on my computer (running MRI 1.9.2p290), defining the reader takes 4ms to execute 100 times. In a production application which might use `find` thousands of times per second, this could eat up a measurable % of total CPU time.

Comment: If the result can be an Array, Hash, *or* ActiveResource::Base, just define `http_response` on those 3 classes, and then you don't have to keep adding the reader dynamically *every time* `find` is called.

Comment: If you really want to keep adding the `http_response` method over and over again every time `find` is called, I found it is 4x faster if you `class_eval` a block rather than a string. Use `to_sym` to convert the method name string to a symbol.

Comment: didn't know that cass_eval faster with block so much, thanks. About  http_method. The main idea is to define method in object (anonimous class of object) not in class, so no matter what object will be return from find method it will have method to access its http response (but not all objects of current class). 
you said that don't know if this code could actually work, though, because class_eval only works when called on modules and classes.
This works because object.class_eval   works as object.singleton_class for me in ruby 1.9.3 , I don't really know if it's normal, need go deeper in it.

Comment: OK, I see. I am running Ruby 1.9.2, so that's why it works for you but not for me. If you want to make this code compatible with earlier versions of Ruby, why don't you do something like: `def result.http_response; @__http_response__; end`

Comment: Alex, can you show me trace or something, because I switched my rvm to ruby-1.9.2-p180 and it still works

Comment: even for 1.8.7 
 => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true> 
1.8.7 :009 > Supplier.get(2).http_response
 => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true> 
1.8.7 :010 >  Supplier.find(2).http_response
 => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true> 
1.8.7 :011 >  Supplier.all.http_response
 => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true>

Comment: `>> [].class_eval "attr_reader :http_response"
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_eval' for []:Array
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'`

Comment: oh I noticed it works from rails console and doesn't work from irb. That means that rails do some magic

Comment: OK, then it should be fine. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'll fix this anyway, in case it will used out of rails

Comment: You're welcome! Please let me know if you push changes to GitHub. Also, did you fix the bug I mentioned with `add_response_method`? See the last part of my edited answer.

Comment: I didn't notice your last part. Can you show example of code with that you tried to do?

Comment: also I found that I can't use alias_method in instance_eval as you wrote.
1.8.7 :070 > ActiveResource::Base.instance_eval do
1.8.7 :071 >     alias_method :__find__, :find
1.8.7 :072?>   end
NameError: undefined method `find' for class `ActiveResource::Base'

Comment: I just tried the same thing. I don't know why `alias_method` doesn't work, but `alias` seems to work fine. Note that with `alias`, you don't need a comma. (It is built in to the language.) So: `alias :__find__ :find`

Comment: @Fivell, just from what I can see here, `add_response_method` contains a classic alias chaining mistake which I have made many times before. Have you tried calling `add_response_method` more than once in the same program on `ActiveResource::Base`?

Comment: I tried but can't reproduce infinite loop

Comment: An example: `>> class Finder; def self.find; end end
=> nil
>> class Finder; def self.add_method; class << self; def find; result = __find__; puts "hi"; result; end end end end
=> nil
>> Finder.add_method
=> nil
>> Finder.add_method
=> nil
>> Finder.find
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!!`

Comment: Did you try calling `ActiveResource::Base.add_response_method` twice in a row, and then using `ActiveResource::Base.find`?

Comment: can reproduce it even if i call add_method more 10 times...very strange..  it's out of my understanding now

Comment: should I remove previously methods before defining them second time?

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `alias_method` *every time* `add_response_method` is called. You should only alias `find` once, when the file is loaded.

Comment: you mean do it globally ? But then it will touch all inherited classes from ActiveResource , even if it not needed .. Is it good ? I thought that it is very flexible when you can redefine methods with aliases obly for specific classes... but when you showed me this problem I don't know how to resolve this conflict.

Comment: what if I'll check before  class_eval unless methods.include?("original_find")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2605/discussion-between-alex-d-and-fivell)

Comment: Just one more: hash lookups are faster with a symbol key than with a string. So why don't you use a symbol key for your thread-local variables, rather than a string?

Comment: will do this i nenxt release